# VBA+MSSQL Transactions - need to work with values created during the transaction

Tags: sql-server, vba, transactions

I have an MS Access application running on Microsoft SQL Server. I have some VBA automation that manipulates the database.

My example: Shipping Orders (tblSalesOrders)

When I click "Ship Order", there are some validation checks and if everything passes, I want to create a Shipment (tblShipments) and Shipment Items (tblShipmentDetails). Let's not dig to deep into my design, I want to keep this quite generic if possible.

Of course **I want to use SQL Transactions** to ensure data integrity.

This is my VBA Code (**Conn** is my ADO Connection, **Exec** is my custom built function to execute SQL command within Conn):

```
intSalesOrderID = Forms!frmSalesOrderDetails!SalesOrderID
        
Conn.BeginTrans

Exec "INSERT INTO tbl1Shipments (CustomerID, DateShipped) " & _
        "VALUES (" & DLookup("CustomerID", "dbo_tbl1SalesOrders", "SalesOrderID=" & intSalesOrderID) & ", " & _
                     "GETDATE())"
               
intShipmentID = DMax("ShipmentID", "dbo_tbl1Shipments", "CustomerID=" & DLookup("CustomerID", "dbo_tbl1SalesOrders", "SalesOrderID=" & intSalesOrderID))

Exec "INSERT INTO tbl1ShipmentDetails (ShipmentID, ---RandomColumn1---, ---RandomColumn2)"
        "VALUES (" & intShipmentID & ", " & _
                GetRandomColumn1Somewhere,
                GetRandomColumn2Somewhere)

Conn.CommitTrans
```

The problem is that **I need to extract the ShipmentID from the previously created Shipment, so I can assign the Foreign Key to Shipment Details**. My best idea so far was to use DMAX using the CustomerID as a parameter, but that's probably a bad thing to do...

It doesn't work anyway because I'm still inside the transaction and the Shipment hasn't been truly created yet.

My question is - how to do this correctly? Thanks a lot in advance.

Tomas

Comment: part of doing the above correctly would also be **parametrising** your query; it looks wide open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Surely this is easier to put both INSERTS into a SPROC and have the transaction handling inside that?  Assuming that ShipmentID is an IDENTITY value, you can then use SCOPE_IDENTITY() to capture the ID from the first INSERT to then use in the second INSERT

Comment: As for the injection attacks: Thanks for the input. This is stuff I dealt with here before and we agreed that it's not important for my particular application to be concerned with. Furthermore, every piece of the information is generated automatically, not by a user.

Comment: is the stuff executed against sql server? You could use SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() to get the last generated identity and then get it back in the same code as the insert, or even combine both in a single exec command?

Comment: IF DMAX (whatever that is) is executed in the same transaction, it should see the maximum value btw.

Comment: Yes, it's against SQL Server. I will definitely look into the SCOPE_IDENTITY() thing. DMAX is a VBA function. It appears that the data are not saved into the actual SQL Server table until the transaction is committed, therefore MS Access doesn't see the value.

Comment: Injection attacks are not just about security, it's also about correctness. What happens if someone puts a `'` in one of the fields?

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution based on the comments provided. The comments suggested that I should use SCOPE_IDENTITY() to capture the ID. However, this wouldn't work because it captures the last ID inserted in ANY table. If I inserted more rows in tbl1ShipmentDetails, then the SCOPE_IDENTITY would indicate the last ID of a ShipmentDetail, not the Shipment itself.

I used **IDENT_CURRENT('tbl1Shipments')** instead and works perfectly.

The final working code:

```
intSalesOrderID = Forms!frmSalesOrderDetails!SalesOrderID
        
Conn.BeginTrans

Exec "INSERT INTO tbl1Shipments (CustomerID, ShippingMethodID, ShipToID, CarrierID) " & _
        "VALUES (" & DLookup("CustomerID", "dbo_tbl1SalesOrders", "SalesOrderID=" & intSalesOrderID) & ", " & _
                DLookup("ShippingMethodID", "dbo_tbl1SalesOrders", "SalesOrderID=" & intSalesOrderID) & ", " & _
                DLookup("ShipToID", "dbo_tbl1SalesOrders", "SalesOrderID=" & intSalesOrderID) & ", " & _
                DLookup("CarrierID", "dbo_tbl1SalesOrders", "SalesOrderID=" & intSalesOrderID) & ")"

Exec "INSERT INTO tbl1ShipmentDetails (ShipmentID, SalesOrderDetailID, Quantity) " & _
        "SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('tbl1Shipments'), SalesOrderDetailID, ToShip " & _
            "FROM ##TempShipOrder"

Conn.CommitTrans
```

Comment: "it captures the last ID inserted in ANY table" yes but the idea is you can store the `SCOPE_IDENTITY` in a variable immediately after inserting. `IDENT_CURRENT` doesn't work properly when triggers are involved, or when another session is inserting at the same time. Your other option is an `OUTPUT` clause, see linked question.

Comment: Yeah, i mentioned you should get the two scripts together into one... IDENT_CURRENT is as bad as using MAX, because someone else might beat you and insert another value